# If(calender.getTime().after(new Date...)) is always true...?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an app which has two different themes (declared in `styles.xml`) - light mode and dark mode. I wanted to try to get the dark mode to turn on automatically at a certain time using `java.util.Calender` and `java.util.Date`.

The if-statement I was working with was supposed to set the theme to DarkTheme after 22:00 (10pm). I was working around 1pm and I changed the code to `10, 0` and `15, 0` to test it, but the statement was somehow always true.

I got it fixed now using a different method, but I just really wanted to know why what I tried before didn't work. Maybe I'm an idiot and don't a very simple mistake I made, but logically thinking I can't find what's wrong.

(FYI, I'm working with Android Studio 3.4.1, if that would make any difference.)

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        calender.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
        if (calender.getTime().after(new Date(calender.getTime().getYear(), calender.getTime().getMonth(), calender.getTime().getDay(), 22, 0))) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        }
        else {
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calender.getTime().getDay()` [returns the day of the week](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay()) (I've referenced the JDK7 class, which should have the same semantics as the one in Android) and NOT the day of the month (as expected by the Date constructor). Replace this with `calendar.getTime().getDate()`.

Comment: Worked, thanks alot! I'm glad the issue was just as simple as me not using the constructer correctly.